# Usage and determination of the arguments of quadprog::solve.QP

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, quadratic, quadratic-programming, quadprog

The function of quadprog looks like that: `solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq=0, factorized=FALSE)`

My objective function is: [image]

And my two constraints are: [image]

Now my aim is to determine the single arguments.

**1) First argument** `Dmat`:

In the generel notation is: [image]

Calculation matrix **D** which is `Dmat`:

[image]

And because **D** is symmetric, the solution is

[image]

**2) Second argument** `dvec`: The linear part of the objective function

[image]

**3) Third argument** `Amat`: This is the left-hand-side of the constraints

[image]

**4) Forth argument** `bvec`: This is the right-hand-side of the constraints

[image]

**5) Fifth argument** `meq` is zero because of only inequality constraints

**6) Sixth argument** `factorized`: see question

**And now** I have to put these six arguments in the function `solve.QP()`. But here I'm sure that there's a need of further "transformation"...

- When you look at the [package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/quadprog.pdf) the quadratic part is multiplied by 0.5 and the linear part is negativ

[image]

- Also the constraints are differently defined - >= sign

[image]

**Questions**:

1. How must I "transform" the first four arguments of `solve.QP()`
2. What does the last argument `factorized` affect
3. How can I maximize the function `solve.QP()`

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I have done now my "transformation" like suggested in the link from  G. Grothendieck - I hope I have done everything right?!

[image]

And when I change the argument `factorized=TRUE` then I get my expected solution with x1=2 and x2=4.

[image]

In the help a R^-1 is mentioned. But sadly I have no clue what that means... Any hints appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There is an example at the bottom of the ?solve.QP page.  There are also some examples here http://www.fsb.miamioh.edu/lij14/400_slide_qp.pdf and there are other quadratic optimization functions in R packages listed here https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I added an edit to my post. Is it possible to check it?! That would be awesome... and I think maximize a QP isn't possible at all?! And can you also please give me a hint to the argument `factorized`? Tahnks a lot!

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: An additionally question: How is it possible to restrict the range of an variable and add that to the matrix Amat? I mean something like  `2<=x1<=12`. Is it possible with `quadprog::solve.QP`?

Comment: If the documentation I have already pointed to is insufficient, and it does look ambiguous to me, just don't  use solve.QP and use a different one from the Optimization Task View.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: And which solver can you suggest?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: And when the convex problem becomes larger?