# Multiply two variables in an objective function using cvxr

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, cvx, cvxr

I want to minimize the following objective function

[image: objective_function]

with some constraints

[image: constraints]

And another user (I think it was [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck)) suggested to use the `CVXR` package of R.

So I followed the instructions on [A Gentle Introduction to CVXR](https://cvxr.rbind.io/cvxr_examples/cvxr_gentle-intro/) to make my code

```
library(CVXR)  # if necessary
x <- Variable(1)
y <- Variable(1)
objective <- Minimize(5*x^2 + 14*x*y + 10*y^2 -76*x -108*y +292)
constraints <- list(x >= 0, y >= 0, x + 2*y <=10, x + y<=6)
prob_OF <- Problem(objective, constraints)
solution_OF <- solve(prob_OF)  # and here the error occured

## Error in construct_intermediate_chain(object, candidate_solvers, gp = gp): Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

On [How to convert quadratic to linear program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774270/how-to-convert-quadratic-to-linear-program)
 I found the hint to the [McCormick envelopes](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes) that helps to solve the issue with the bilinear formular part [image: part_of_OF]. Especially the [image: part_of_OF] part.

At the end of the answer of [josliber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093387/josliber) he remarks, that all the variables should have a bound. In my constraints there is no upper bound and therefore I insert an upper bound. It's an arbitrary choice. You have to recalculate with new bounds if the solution is on the bound...

```
library(CVXR)  # if necessary
x <- Variable(1)
y <- Variable(1)
w <- Variable(1)
objective <- Minimize(5*x^2 + 14*w + 10*y^2 -76*x -108*y +292)
constraints <- list(x >= 0, x <= 100,
                    y >= 0, y <= 100,
                    x+2*y <= 10, 
                    x+y <= 6,
                    w >= 0, w >= 100*x + 100*y - 10000,  # constraints according to McCormick envelopes
                    w <= 100*y, w <= 100*x)  # constraints according to McCormick envelopes
prob_OF <- Problem(objective, constraints)
solution_OF <- solve(prob_OF)
solution_OF$value
## -125.0667
solution_OF$getValue(x)                  
## 2.933333
solution_OF$getValue(y)
## 3.066667
solution_OF$getValue(w)
## 1.000135e-30
```

Here the solution is not my expected one... When I solve the same objective function with `solve.QP()` then I get [image: result_x] and [image: result_y]. For establishing the code look at my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912192/usage-and-determination-of-the-arguments-of-quadprogsolve-qp)...

Let's check the code:

```
# Parameters of the objective funtion and the constraints
D=matrix(c(5,7,7,10),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
d=c(-78,-108)
A=matrix(c(1,2,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
b=c(10,6)

# Convert the parameters to an appropriate state of solve.QP()
Dmat=2*D
dvec=-d
Amat=-t(A)
bvec=-b

# load the package and run solve.QP()
library(quadprog)
solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec,meq=0,factorized=TRUE)
## $solution
## [1] 2 4     # these are the x and y results
##
## $value
## -587.9768
##
## and some more results...
```

**Question**:

- Why are the two results different?

  - In which of the solving alternatives I have done any mistakes? Is it possible to point them out?
- And when I put in the x and y from the results I don't get the `$value` of the `solve.QP()` alternatives

  - When doing the math [image: formula_question]
  - And as you can see the results don't coincide
  - Am I doing here an mistake?!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: My recommendation in a comment was that you review the examples of solve.,QP and the Optimization Task View.  When I mentioned CVXR in a separate comment it was in the context of what optimization packages I often use, not in the context that it was necessarily appropriate to your problem. Regarding McCormick, it is not an equivalent formulation; it is a relaxation of the original problem whose solution gives a lower bound to the original problem.  The lower bound may equal the solution to the original problem but there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: I'm new to the optimization topic and therefore I'm happy if someone suggests me an solver which he often uses. I'm aware that there are other solvers that might fit better... Thanks for the hint, that McCormick is a relaxation! Then I think I have to split my bound in multiple intervals like mentioned by josliber to get the exact values. Can you please explain why the `$solution` of `solve.QP()` yields in `-587.9768`? When I put the `x=2` and `y=4` in the objective function I get `0`.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: I think the correct values are `x=3` and `y=3`. Perhaps the task of the workbook is wrong, because here are `x=2` and `y=4`.  But one thing I'm still wondering: Why is the result in the objective function with `f(x=3,y=3)=-291` and  `solver.QP$value=-297`? Is this caused by rounding errors?! The two results occur when omitting `meq` and `factorized`.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Yes that's true, but taking the objective function `f(x,y)=5*x^2 + 14*x*y + 10*y^2 -76*x -108*y=5*3^2 + 14*3*3 + 10*3^2 -76*3 -108*3=-291`

Comment: I have moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are that

1. the question is using factorized=TRUE
2. the objective function at the top of the question implies a different dvec[1] than shown in the code in the question.

If we omit factorized (default is FALSE) and consistently use the code in the question that defines Dmat, dvec, Amat and bvec then we get consistent results from solve.QP and manually computing the objective based on the solution vector, both being -297.  The code until ###### is copied verbatim from the question.

```
# Parameters of the objective funtion and the constraints
D=matrix(c(5,7,7,10),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
d=c(-78,-108) 
A=matrix(c(1,2,1,1),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
b=c(10,6)

# Convert the parameters to an appropriate state of solve.QP()
Dmat=2*D
dvec=-d
Amat=-t(A)
bvec=-b

######

library(quadprog)
ans <- solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec)
str(ans)
## List of 6
##  $ solution              : num [1:2] 3 3
##  $ value                 : num -297
##  ...snip...

# manual calculation of objective function
t(ans$solution) %*% Dmat %*% ans$solution / 2 - dvec %*% ans$solution
##      [,1]
## [1,] -297

# another manual calculation - coefficients come from Dmat and dvec
f <- function(x, y) (10 * x^2 + 2 * 14 * x * y + 20 * y^2) / 2 - (78 * x + 108 * y)
f(3, 3)
## [1] -297
```

Comment: Like mentioned above: Yes that's true, but taking the objective function as shown at the top of my question - this is the result: `f(x,y)=5*x^2 + 14*x*y + 10*y^2 -76*x -108*y=5*3^2 + 14*3*3 + 10*3^2 -76*3 -108*3=-291`. Why are the results different respectively why not all three methods lead to the same result? **1)** `solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec)$value=-297` **2)**  `t(ans$solution) %*% Dmat %*% ans$solution / 2 - dvec %*% ans$solution=-297` and **3)** `f(3,3)=5*3^2 + 14*3*3 + 10*3^2 -76*3 -108*3=-291`

Comment: And why are you taking `78*x` instead of `76*x`? Here arises the difference of `6`...

Comment: I have prescribed :-/ When you look proper at my question I use `76` and `78`... My fault. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Have moved my comment to the answer.